# CAST unsigned to signed int in MySql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select numbers from database stored as unsigned tinyint
But on the output i need them to be negative.

This is what i do:

```
SELECT
 -CAST(sales_shipments_items.qty AS SIGNED INTEGER) AS qty,
FROM sales_shipments_items
WHERE 1
```

& this works on my local machine with mysql 5.5.25
But returns 0's on the server with mysql 5.5.32-cll-lve

BTW, on my local machine I do not even have to use CAST it works without it.

I tried to use CONVERT instead of CAST but still only get 0's

Sample data in `sales_shipments_items`

```
id|type|shp_num|qty
3   1   3321   2

4   1   3322   2

5   2   3321   2

6   3   3320   1

7   4   3350   1

8   5   3351   3
```

I'm expecting to see:

```
-2
-2
-2
-1
-1
-3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why complicate it? You can simply do:

```
SELECT (0 - qty) AS qty
FROM sales_shipments_items
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81919/1)**

As Jungsu noticed this does not work when your field is `UNSIGNED`, in that case you can run this query:

```
SELECT qty/-1 AS qty
FROM sales_shipments_items
```

Comment: Comes up with BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(0 - `krumaneq_ordering`.`sales_shipments_items`.`qty`)'

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question? an expected output?

Comment: It just doesnt work on server. No problems with local output. It this a mysql bug in that particular version & should I report it to hoster?

Comment: @AnKing I think you need to change `BIGINT UNSIGNED` to `BIGINT`.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky If you create qty as BIGINT UNSIGNED, It will not work.

Comment: right now i have it stored as tynyint unsigned & I want to store it as that. I can not believe it is a problem to convert on the output?

Comment: Yes let it remain `unsigned`, try the second query I have there

Comment: `qty * -1` does not work. but `qty / -1` works fine, what's the difference?

Comment: Perfect it worked... i have a weird formation on the output like '-1.0000' but its better anyhow

Comment: You can round it off :)

Answer (score 8):

This works always. (`MYSQL 5.6`)

```
SELECT -1 * CAST(qty as SIGNED) as qty
FROM sales_shipments_items
```